# Hogan doesn't support lambda in precompiled mode

Tags: javascript, lambda, mustache, precompiled, hogan.js

I have a mustache template with a lambda looking like this:

```
{{#myfunc}}myvalue{{/myfunc}}
```

It is precompiled by hogan.js to look like this:

```
define(['hogan'], 
function (Hogan) {
    var template = new Hogan.Template(function (c, p, i) {
        var _ = this;
        _.b(i = i || "");
        if (_.s(_.f("myfunc", c, p, 1), c, p, 0, 11, 18, "{{ }}")) {
            _.rs(c, p, function (c, p, _) {
                _.b("myvalue");
            });
            c.pop();
        }
        return _.fl();;
    });
    return function (context, partial, indent) {
        return template.render(context, partial, indent);
    };
});
```

I render the template using a Marionette.ItemView passing the lambda function into the Backbone.Model like this:

```
myfunc: function (key) { console.log("key", key); }
```

The weird thing: The function myfunc will be called and log to the console but it isn't passed a key by the template.
I read about Hogan not supporting Lambda in precompiled mode (about a year ago - i guess this is fixed) - but if so how does it happen, that myfunc is called at all?

I put some debugging into my vendor/hogan.js lib - it looks like hogan cannot see the value between lambda-tags (here: myvalue).

Anyone seen this before?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: no, just avoided precompling. there was a patch on github but I didn't manage to get it running.

Answer (score 1):

**My investigation**:
the problem occurs only while using grunt plugins such as grunt-hogan or grunt-templates-hogan.
If compile a template before rendering inline in script with `Hogan.compile()` the issue is resolved.

I create a small project on github, because jsfiddle doesn't allow to use grunt and link it to issue https://github.com/twitter/hogan.js/issues/225.

Project: https://github.com/ssuvorov/hogan-issue

My solution was to replace lambdas with necessary object fields. I mean prepare data with all necessary information before rendering.